# What is the probability of the survival of a tribble?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, probability

You have a population of `k` Tribbles. This particular species of Tribbles live for exactly one day and then die. Just before death, a single Tribble has the probability `P_i` of giving birth to `i` more Tribbles. What is the probability that after m generations, every Tribble will be dead?

Is my analysis right? If it is right, why it not matching the [output](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/110/11021.pdf)?

```
Case 1:
```

Number of tribbles: `k = 1`

Number of generations: `m = 1`

Probabilities: `P_0 = 0.33 P_1 = 0.34 P_2 = 0.33`

The probability that after `1` generation every Tribble would be dead `= P_0 = 0.33`

```
Case 2:
```

Number of tribbles: `k = 1`

Number of generations: `m = 2`

Probabilities: `P_0 = 0.33 P_1 = 0.34 P_2 = 0.33`

Each tribble can have either `0` or `1` or `2` children.

At the end of the first year there has to be at least one tribble to ensure that there are tribbles in the second generation also.

The tribble of the first generation should have `1` or `2` children. So, the number of tribbles at the end of the first year would be either `1` or `2` with probabilities `P_1=0.34 P_1=0.34` and `P_2=0.33 P_2=0.33` respectively.

If there is to be no children after the second generation, none of these children should have children of their own.

If there is `1` child in the second generation, the probability it would have no children is `P_0=0.33`

If there are `2` children in the second generation, the probability that none of them would have children is `(P_0)^2=(0.33)^2=0.1089`

The probability that after `2` generations every tribble would be dead is the probability of there being `1` child times the probability of it not having children plus the probability of there being `2` children times the probability of none of them having children =`0.34×0.33+0.33×0.0.1089=0.148137`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss 1st generation 0 child case

The correct equation is

> P0 x 1 + P1 x P0 + P2 x P0^2

= 0.33 + 0.34 x 0.33 + 0.33 x (0.33)^2

= 0.478137